# Drag and drop элементов списка

Tags: javascript

Хочу сделать перетягивания выбранного элемента списка по клику. Но возникает проблема, что бы перетянуть элемент нужно кликнуть два раза на него. А также нужно что бы при клике на элемент создавалась его копия, так как один элемент может использоваться несколько раз.

```
    document.querySelector('#drag-training_1').addEventListener('click', function(e){ 
    var id = e.target.id;
    var el = document.getElementById(id);
    var element = el;

    element.onmousedown = function(e) {
        element.style.position = 'absolute';
        element.style.cursor = 'pointer';
        moveAt(e);
        document.body.appendChild(element);
        element.style.zIndex = 1000; 

        document.onmousemove = function(e) {
            moveAt(e);
        }

        element.onmouseup = function() {
            document.onmousemove = null;
            element.onmouseup = null;
        }

        element.ondragstart = function() {
            return true;
        };

        function moveAt(e) {
            element.style.left = e.pageX - element.offsetWidth / 2 + 'px';
            element.style.top = e.pageY - element.offsetHeight / 2 + 'px';
        }
    }

});
```

Подробнее можно увидеть [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lk31z2q2/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Там чуть иначе следовало бы сделать. В частности, не нужно вкладывать всю привязку событий непосредственно в `onmousedown`. А чтобы клонировать элемент, можно использовать метод [`cloneNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode). У меня получилось что-то такое:

```
var drags = document.querySelectorAll('.drag-element > *'),
    moveAt = function(element, e) {
        element.style.left = e.pageX - element.offsetWidth / 2 + 'px';
        element.style.top = e.pageY - element.offsetHeight / 2 + 'px';
    };

for (var i = drags.length; i-- ;) {
    var drag = drags[i],
        element;

    drag.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
        element = this.cloneNode(true);
        element.style.position = 'absolute';
        element.style.zIndex = 1000;
        moveAt(element, e);
        document.body.appendChild(element);
    }, false);

    document.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
        element && moveAt(element, e);
    }, false);

    document.addEventListener('mouseup', function() {
        // здесь следует произвести какое-нибудь действие с `element`
        // чтобы не оставлять элемент где попало
        element = null;
    }, false);
}
```

**ДЕМО:** http://jsfiddle.net/Lk31z2q2/5/

Comment: а как что бы при клике на элемент он сначала не клонировался, а привязывался к курсору мыши, и уже после клика на область клонировался. Типа как это я сделал в своем коде вот http://jsfiddle.net/Lk31z2q2/7/